# Issues rendering Emoji characters in Android email

Tags: android, html, emoji, email

I'm working on making a small survey app and I want to send out an email that has a simple thumbs up and thumbs down button. I figured I could use emoji instead of images in the email.

The problem is when the email is sent to an Android device, it doesn't render the emoji characters. I've narrowed the problem down to sizing. If I make the emoji bigger, it disappears. Using the small emoji and it works; screenshots are attached. I've tried on a few Android devices including a Samsung S6 and Google Pixel. I've also tried using the built in Mail app as well as Outlook on Android with the same results.

Has anyone got this working?

**Missing Emoji Screenshot**

- [Android Large Emoji](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwXxU.png)

**Working Emoji Screenshot**

- [Outlook, Android, iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmZBY.jpg)

**Snippet of the HTML in my email message**

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td style="width:60px;background-color:#fff;">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color:#5cb85c; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px;">
          <a href="http://intranet/" target="_blank" title="thumbs up" style="text-decoration: none; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; padding: 12px 18px; border: 1px solid #4cae4c; display: inline-block;"><strong style="color: #fff;font-size:60pt;"></strong></a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td style="width:10px;background-color:#fff;"></td>
  <td style="width:60px;background-color:#fff;">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color:#e9703e; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px;">
          <a href="http://intranet/" target="_blank" title="thumbs down" style="text-decoration: none; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; padding: 12px 18px; border: 1px solid #e9703e; display: inline-block;"><strong style="color: #fff;font-size:60pt;"></strong></a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</table>
```

**Update 1** - Fixed the Android Large Emoji image
**Update 2** - Add html I used in the example screenshots.

Comment: You shared same link twice. Please, fix first link.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I fixed the link